# SqlParameterSource with SQL expression as it's value

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-jdbc

in my java application i use SimpleJdbcInsert.

i create a MapSqlParameterSource to create a mapped parameters in order to add rows using SimpleJdbcInsert.

the problem is that I want to add an SQL Expression to one of the parameters.

for example `curdate()` which returns current date. if i'll just use

```
new  MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("val","curdate()");
```

it will understand that curdate is a string. how can I let it know that it's an SQL expression ?

Comment: Maybe using a database function is too advanced for the `SimpleJdbcInsert` and you have to use `JdbcTemplate`

Comment: maybe :) I just want to be sure.